# Alternative of Android emulator to run an application using WiFi-Direct

Tags: android-emulator, wifi-direct

I have read that android emulator can't run applications using the WiFi-Direct, and I want to ask if there is another solution without using a real device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay run two x86 images via Virtualbox in VB settings:

Settings --> Wireless & Networks --> More... --> Wi-Fi direct

Comment: please can u give me a link to download the x86 ?  thanks again.

Comment: easiest way is genymotion.com

Comment: i tried to install android x86 6.0 and wifi direct is not available.

Answer (score 0):

Android-x86 - Porting Android to x86 link,
http://www.android-x86.org/download

Comment: Wifi-Direct is not available, at least in the version android-x86 Android 6.0. Not sure if you could manage with other version or other virtualbox network settings.